# Groovy MissingMethodException with signature when accessing getter and NoSuchMethodError on inheritance

Tags: groovy, dependency-management

## Can you explain why sometimes groovy throws MissingMethodException when java code calls a getter and there's a property with the same name?

Secondary question:

## Can you explain why my first work-around is invalid for the 2nd use case?

The following script works because I added **methodMissing**

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy    
@Grapes([
    @Grab(group='org.jvnet.hudson', module='xstream', version='1.4.7-jenkins-1'),
])
def a

println 'xstream'
com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream s = new com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream()
println s
def reg1 = s.converterRegistry
println "using property: $reg1"

com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.metaClass.methodMissing = { String name, def args ->
    println "missing $name"
    if (name=="getConverterRegistry") {
        return delegate.converterRegistry
    }
}

def reg2 = s.getConverterRegistry()
println "using getter  : $reg2"

println "ok"
```

This script prints:

```
com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream@6c45ee6e
using property: com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream$2@2e8e8225
missing getConverterRegistry
using getter  : com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream$2@2e8e8225
ok
```

The method getConverterRegistry exists in [XStream](https://github.com/jenkinsci/xstream/blob/master/xstream/src/java/com/thoughtworks/xstream/XStream.java) but if you comment out the methodMissing you get :
**groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.getConverterRegistry()** is applicable for argument types: () values: []
        at TestXStream.run(TestXStream.groovy:24)

I was full of hope when making this work (although it's not pretty) but my issue continues because my code is actually using jenkins library and the following code does not work:

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy

import hudson.util.XStream2
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream

@Grapes([
    @Grab(group='org.jvnet.hudson', module='xstream', version='1.4.7-jenkins-1'),
    @Grab(group='org.jenkins-ci.main', module='jenkins-core', version='1.642.3', transitive=false),
])
def a

XStream.metaClass.methodMissing = { String name, def args ->
    println "missing $name for XStream"
    if (name=="getConverterRegistry") {
        return delegate.converterRegistry
    }
}

def reg2 = new XStream().getConverterRegistry()
println reg2

XStream2.metaClass.methodMissing = { String name, def args ->
    println "missing $name for XStream2"
    if (name=="getConverterRegistry") {
        return delegate.converterRegistry
    }
}

println 'xstream2'
XStream2 s2 = new XStream2() // internal call to this.getConverterRegistry()
println "ok"
```

And the output:

```
missing getConverterRegistry for XStream
com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream$2@c2db68f
xstream2
Caught: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: hudson.util.XStream2.getConverterRegistry()Lcom/thoughtworks/xstream/converters/ConverterRegistry;
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: hudson.util.XStream2.getConverterRegistry()Lcom/thoughtworks/xstream/converters/ConverterRegistry;
        at hudson.util.XStream2.wrapMapper(XStream2.java:188)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.buildMapper(XStream.java:610)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.<init>(XStream.java:568)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.<init>(XStream.java:496)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.<init>(XStream.java:465)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.<init>(XStream.java:411)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.<init>(XStream.java:350)
        at hudson.util.XStream2.<init>(XStream2.java:89)
        at TestXStream2.run(TestXStream2.groovy:33)
```

Class XStream contains a property converterRegistry and its getter.
XStream2 extends XStream and the getter is inherited.

Note that when I run this from eclipse it's working fine and when using CLI I have this issue; possibly because eclipse would change this code more than the compiler.

Any clues?

Comment: When you say "XStream contains a property converterRegistry and its getter" you mean `XStream::getConverterRegistry` is not in XStream's source code, right? You are talking about the one you added through metaprogramming?

Comment: I'm using the jenkins custom version: (https://github.com/jenkinsci/xstream/blob/1.4.7-jenkins-1/xstream/src/java/com/thoughtworks/xstream/XStream.java#L1493).
(Thanks for having a look BTW)

Comment: After spending some more time on it I didn't manage to find out if it's an issue related to grape or groovy or if I missed something.

I finally decided to switch my entry point to a Java main and with what should be the same classpath it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dropped the issue by switching back to plain Java for the main launcher.
I use the same über jar as a dependency as when I used groovy and grape.

I don't know wether it's related to groovy or grape (I suspect groovy) but I worked around it.